# C++, Visual Studio 2017: Access a global variable of an .exe from within a loaded .dll

Tags: c++, dll

I have the deplorable mission the access a global(!) variable of a .exe from within my .dll (loaded by that .exe).

A header file gives me following declaration of the global variable:

```
extern Element *ops_TheActiveElement;
```

Basically, the global variable is a pointer to a class instance which i need to acess.

From what I found on the web, i could use something like this from within the dll:

```
Element* getTheActiveElement()
{

auto handle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

if (handle == NULL)
    std::cout << "handle" << handle << std::endl;

auto activeElement = GetProcAddress(handle, "ops_TheActiveElement") ;

return (Element*)activeElement;
}
```

Getting the module handle is fine, but getting the address of the global variable fails.
I am not sure, if this is possible at all since i am not familiar with Windows programming.
What could be a possible approach? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can check out exported symbols with `dumpbin /exports`. If that variable is not exported, then you cannot use `GetProcAddress` to get it (usually an exe doesn't export anything). Of course, you can find that variable using a disassembler and some reverse engineering work.

Answer (score 0):

- Proffered approach would be to supply this variable explicitly when invoking code from your library. Use of `extern` (except for `extern "C"` functions) and use of global variables are a code smell.
- Alternatively you can export this variable from executable and link you dll to executable so `ops_TheActiveElement` can be accessed directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot make modifications to the .exe.

Comment: @macmallow Then you should stick with the dll interface it supports without trying to access some implementation specific details that is not exposed to dll.

Comment: @VTT Not really useful for hacking/cheating with code injection ^_^